# How to label parallels/meridian on orthographic projection using matplotlib/basemap in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to label parallels/meridians on orthographic projection using matplotlib/basemap in python. According to the basemap documents labeling does not work for orthographic and some other projections by  `drawparalles(parallels,labeles=[left,right,top,bottom])` command, it has to be done manually. Can anybody suggest me any method to label parallels/meridians manually.

```
lon2,lat2=m1(lon,lat)
lon3,lat3=m1(lon1,lat1)
cax1=m1.pcolor(lon2,lat2,data1,cmap='jet')
colob=plt.colorbar(fraction=0.05)
colob.set_label(r"Diff. Flux $[cm^{-2}Sr^{-1}s^{-1}]$")
parallels = np.arange(-90,90,15.)
cax4=m1.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0])
meridian = np.arange(0,360,15.)
cax5=m1.drawmeridians(meridian,labels=[0,0,0,1])
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround solution using `matplotlib.annotate` command.

```
lon2,lat2=m1(lon,lat)
lon3,lat3=m1(lon1,lat1)
cax1=m1.pcolor(lon2,lat2,data1,cmap='jet')
colob=plt.colorbar(fraction=0.05)
colob.set_label(r"Diff. Flux $[cm^{-2}Sr^{-1}s^{-1}]$")
parallels = np.arange(-90,90,15.)
cax4=m1.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0])
meridian = np.arange(0,360,15.)
cax5=m1.drawmeridians(meridian,labels=[0,0,0,1])
for i in np.arange(len(meridian)):
    plt.annotate(np.str(meridian[i]),xy=m1(meridian[i],0),xycoords='data')
for i in np.arange(len(parallels)):
    plt.annotate(np.str(parallels[i]),xy=m1(180,parallels[i]),xycoords='data')
```